# pg_dumpall - Azure Database for PostgreSQL - permission denied for database "azure_maintenance"

Tags: postgresql, azure, pg-dumpall

> PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dumpall  -h
>   mydbname.postgres.database.azure.com -p 5432 -U admin@mydbname
>
> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "azure_maintenance"
>   failed: FATAL:  permission denied for database "azure_maintenance"
>   DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege. pg_dumpall: pg_dump
>   failed on database "azure_maintenance", exiting

How would you backup all db's in Azure Postgresql hosted service?

Comment: is there a particular reason why you want this done on azure_maintenance db? you should be able to do this for all user databases without an issue but as far as azure_maintenance db, users do not have the required access to perform this.

Comment: how did you get it sorted ?

Comment: I list db-names in separate script, and dump one by one:/

Comment: Also trying to do this with pg_dumpall and having the same issue. Is there any way to avoid doing it one by one? Or any better way to dump and restore 300+ medium sized DB's on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Since PostgreSQL 12.0 pg_dumpall has a `--exclude-database` option (see [Release Notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/12.0/)).
Following should work:

```sh
pg_dumpall -h mydbname.postgres.database.azure.com -p 5432 -U admin@mydbname --exclude-database=azure* --clean --file=dump.sql
```

Comment: ```pg_dumpall: error: query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for table pg_authid
pg_dumpall: error: query was: SELECT rolname FROM pg_authid WHERE rolname !~ '^pg_' ORDER BY 1
```